# How do I best combine several documents?

Tags: best-practices, input, include

I have a collection of articles written in latex, and I would like to "merge" them into a larger thesis document, in which each article will be a chapter. I have been looking at `include` and `input`, which are great if you start with the meta-document in mind. However in my articles I have sometimes a bit exotic dependencies, such as `dot2texi`, and using the naive approach fails rather abysmally with all kinds of broken paths.

So I was wondering, do you recommend any "best practices" for merging non-trivial documents -- which packages to look at, or to avoid at all cost, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the `combine` package.

Comment: You can also look at `pgfpages`.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the techniques described here:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116665/cross-referencing-between-files-and-equation-counters

Comment: @recluze: Is there `pgfpages` installed in your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are packages to combine documents, they all impose at least some requirements on the nature of the included items. Thus the most general way to deal with the problem is to typeset the parts separately then combine the resulting PDF files, probably using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages). To get page numbering correct, the usual approach is to suppress it in the individual PDF files and add page numbers at the combination stage. To give more detail, we'll need to have more information on the files to be combined: for example, cross-referencing may be required, which can be done using [`xr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xr) (see for example [Cross-referencing between files and equation counters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116665/cross-referencing-between-files-and-equation-counters)).