# Cross-referencing between files and equation counters

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I am using package `xr` to cross reference between two files.

Is there a way to make the equation numbers in one of the files follow the ones in the other? What I mean is, if the last equation in file A is say (28), then the first equation in file (B) be (29) and so on.

Another question is, can this be done with counters for lemmas, theorems, etc?

Comment: I am interested in the answer for this, ie, imagine producing a multi-compendium book series...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using package `zref`:

### Document A

The first document `test-A.tex` writes the latest value of counter `equation` in the `zref` reference `eq-last`:

```
% test-A.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-base}
\usepackage{atveryend}
\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \if@filesw   
    \begingroup
      \zref@setcurrent{default}{\the\value{equation}}%
      \zref@wrapper@immediate{%
        \zref@labelbyprops{eq-last}{default}%
      }%
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}E=mc^2\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Remarks:

- Instead of `\AtEndDocument` it uses the hook `\AfterLastShipout` that is executed after the last page is shipped out and before the `.aux` file is closed.
- `\zref@wrapper@immediate` maps `\write` to `\immediate\write` in order to
  write into the `.aux` file directly. At this point deferred writing without `\immediate` will not work, because the last page is already shipped out and there is no next page.
- The code is put inside `\if@filesw` and `\fi`. That supports `\nofiles`, that forbids writing to auxiliary files.

### Document B

The next "book in the series" imports the references from document `test-A`. The reference  names are prefixed with `A-` to avoid name clashes (`\zexternaldocument`):

```
% test-B.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-xr}
\makeatletter
\zexternaldocument[A-]{test-A}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\zref@extractdefault{A-eq-last}{default}{0}}%
  \zref@refused{A-eq-last}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}v=\frac{s}{t}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Remarks:

- `\zref@extractdefault` is expandable and can be directly used inside the value part of `\setcounter`.
- `\zref@refused` complains, if the reference is not defined.
  LaTeX clears the warning status for undefined refernces in `\begin{document}`.
  Thus we need `\AtBeginDocument` (otherwise the final "`LaTeX warning: There were undefined references.`" might be missing).

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to prefix reference names from the previous document with `A-`. I tried to remove `[A-]` and changed `A-eq-last` to `eq-last`, to no effect. If I add the lines `\usepackage{xr}` and `\externaldocument{A-test}` early on, it seems to work.

Comment: Also, do you have a short write-up  about those `zref` commands? I mean more explanation of the inner workings. What is `\the\value` construct and why you need to change and read `default`. What is `default` anyway?

Comment: @passerby51 There is the [documentation of package `zref`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/zref.pdf). `\value{<counter>}` returns the count register for the LaTeX counter `<counter>`. Here `\the` or `\number` prints the value of the count register.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way.  In this MWE, I save two counters to an external file: `\thesection` and `\theequation`.  Obviously, you can expand the solution to include saving whatever status variables you need to transfer from one document to the next (such as `\thepage`, etc.).

I have created two commands: `\recallstatus` and `\savestatus` that should be invoked, respectively, at the beginning of the document part (except for part 1) and at the end of the document part.  In this MWE, I define them in each preamble, but it would be easier to stuff them into a `multipart.sty` or some name like that for which you could just `\usepackage`.

Here is part 1 of the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{docpart}
\def\savestatus{%
  \newwrite\tempfile%
  \immediate\openout\tempfile=docstatus\arabic{docpart}.dat%
  \immediate\write\tempfile{\thesection}%
  \immediate\write\tempfile{\theequation}%
  \immediate\closeout\tempfile%
}
\newcounter{olddocpart}
\def\recallstatus{%
  \setcounter{olddocpart}{\arabic{docpart}}
  \addtocounter{olddocpart}{-1}
  \newread\rtempfile%
  \openin\rtempfile=docstatus\arabic{olddocpart}.dat%
  \read\rtempfile to \tmp%
  \setcounter{section}{\tmp}
  \read\rtempfile to \tmp%
  \setcounter{equation}{\tmp}%
  \closein\rtempfile%
}

\setcounter{docpart}{1}
\begin{document}
\section{The First Section}
\begin{equation}
y = x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y = 1/x
\end{equation}
\savestatus
\end{document}
```

The `\savestatus` at the end creates a file `docstatus1.dat` that contains the data (current section and equation):

```
1
2
```

Here is part 2 of the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{docpart}
\def\savestatus{%
  \newwrite\tempfile%
  \immediate\openout\tempfile=docstatus\arabic{docpart}.dat%
  \immediate\write\tempfile{\thesection}%
  \immediate\write\tempfile{\theequation}%
  \immediate\closeout\tempfile%
}
\newcounter{olddocpart}
\def\recallstatus{%
  \setcounter{olddocpart}{\arabic{docpart}}
  \addtocounter{olddocpart}{-1}
  \newread\rtempfile%
  \openin\rtempfile=docstatus\arabic{olddocpart}.dat%
  \read\rtempfile to \tmp%
  \setcounter{section}{\tmp}
  \read\rtempfile to \tmp%
  \setcounter{equation}{\tmp}%
  \closein\rtempfile%
}

\setcounter{docpart}{2}
\begin{document}
\recallstatus
\section{The Second Section}
\begin{equation}
y = x^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y = 1/x^2
\end{equation}
\savestatus

\end{document}
```

The first thing it does is read the part 1 data file to reset the appropriate counters.  As you see from the output, it picks up the sectioning and equation numbers where it left off.  At the end, I do another `\savestatus` (which writes `docstatus2.dat`) to prepare for part 3.

Here is the document image from part 1:

[image]

and here it is from part 2:

[image]

Obviously, if you modify a counter in part 1, parts 2, 3, etc. all have to be successively recompiled in order that their counters get updated.